# Is there an active international arrest warrant against Henry Kissinger?

Tags: politics

> [Infowars in 2010](http://www.infowars.com/action-to-arrest-wanted-war-criminal-kissinger-in-ireland/): It seems that Henry Kissinger as Rockefeller’s right hand man had to be at the meeting even though there existed an International arrest warrant from France and Spain who wish to charge him with war crimes from the Chile war. The Spanish and French say Henry Kissinger is implicated in the death of French and Spanish in the war in Chile.

Is this an accurate discription of the situation. Is there an international arrest warrant from Spain and France against Henry Kissinger out there?

Comment: Of course Infowars is a very biased source, but of course it makes even more sense to be skeptical about those then :) +1

Comment: There ought to exists many, many arrest warrants for a person that has caused [hundreds of thousands](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2022/jun/21/leadership-six-studies-in-world-strategy-henry-kissinger-review-lessons-in-diplomacy-from-a-master-of-the-dark-arts) or [millions](https://www.vox.com/2016/5/9/11640562/kissinger-pentagon-award) of [deaths](https://www.salon.com/2016/02/12/henry_kissingers_mad_and_illegal_bombing_what_you_need_to_know_about_his_real_history_and_why_the_sandersclinton_exchange_matters/).

Comment: For more background information Kissinger's wrongdoings the podcast [Behind the bastards](https://www.behindthebastards.com/) have six episodes about him: [1](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/105-behind-the-bastards-29236323/episode/part-one-kissinger-94160733/), [2](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/105-behind-the-bastards-29236323/episode/part-two-kissinger-94268769/), [3](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/105-behind-the-bastards-29236323/episode/part-three-kissinger-94482857/), [4](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/105-behind-the-bastards-29236323/episode/part-four-kissinger-94576769/),

Comment: [5](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/105-behind-the-bastards-29236323/episode/part-five-kissinger-94813303/), [6](https://www.iheart.com/podcast/105-behind-the-bastards-29236323/episode/part-six-kissinger-94899290/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find evidence of an arrest warrant. It sounds like an exaggeration of Kissinger's 2001 visit to Paris. [He was summoned then by a French judge](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/france/1332441/Kissinger-shuns-summons.html) to explain the events of the 1973 coup, but the US Secretary of State intervened and he left the country. It was just a court summons, not an arrest warrant. Wikipedia has a well-cited section of other similar events [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Condor#Henry_Kissinger).

Kissinger was certainly worried about a real arrest happening, however. [Pinochet had been arrested several years earlier in the United Kingdom for his admittedly less covert involvement same events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indictment_and_arrest_of_Augusto_Pinochet), and even though he was eventually released, he had still been interned for several years. [Kissinger even wrote a paper condemning the "judicial tyranny" of international courts](http://www.thirdworldtraveler.com/Kissinger/Pitfalls_Univ_Juris_Kis.html) a few months after his departure from Paris.

But no, no arrest warrant.

Comment: He was not interned for several years. He was under house arrest for 16 months.